# cannot add disk to google VM instance

Tags: google-compute-engine

I cannot add additional disk to google cloud VM instance. Is there some limit? (quotas are OK) I have 6 disks already added. And there is problem with seventh. I tried multiple instances and multiple disks. There is error I get:

```
Editing VM instance "X" failed. Error: Invalid resource usage: 'This feature is not available for this project.'
```

I tried to look for features in project and found nothing. I do exactly same thing as I did dozen times before, but now it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so I found where was a problem. It's bug/problem in google frontend. When I used console command to do this, everything was OK.

```
gcloud compute instances attach-disk [INSTANCE_NAME] --disk [DISK_NAME]
```